# Why is Jquery Multifilter not working well?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to [do this,](https://www.jqueryscript.net/table/jQuery-Plugin-To-Filter-Html-Table-with-Multiple-Criteria-multifilter.html) but when I type something for filtering, I don't get any result. I think is all correct but I don't know. Any help is appreciated

This is my code:

```
<div id="resultado">
    <div class="filtros" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around;">
      <div>
      <input autocomplete='off' class='filter' name='name' placeholder='Proyecto' data-col='Proyecto'/>
      <input autocomplete='off' class='filter' name='name' placeholder='Trabajador' data-col='Trabajador'/>
      <input autocomplete='off' class='filter' name='name' placeholder='Año' data-col='Año'/>
      <input autocomplete='off' class='filter' name='name' placeholder='Mes' data-col='Mes'/> 
      </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table" id="myTable">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
        <th scope="col">Proyecto</th>
        <th scope="col">Trabajador</th>
        <th scope="col">Año</th>
        <th scope="col">Mes</th>
        <th scope="col">Horas totales</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php 
            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                echo "<tr><td>".$row['proyecto']."</td><td>".$row['trabajador']."</td><td>".$row['año']."</td><td>".$row['mes']."</td><td>".$row['Hours']."</td></tr>";
              }
        ?>
        </tbody>
    </table>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.filter').multifilter()
})
</script>
```

EDIT: I IMPORTED MULTIFILTER WELL, BUT THAT ISN'T ON THE CODE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin requires an old jQuery version.

```js
$('.filter').multifilter()
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Filter-Html-Table-with-Multiple-Criteria-multifilter/style.css">
<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/jQuery-Plugin-To-Filter-Html-Table-with-Multiple-Criteria-multifilter/multifilter.js"></script>

<div id="resultado">
    <div class="filtros" style="display: flex; justify-content: space-around;">
        <div>
            <input autocomplete='off' class='filter' name='Proyecto' placeholder='Proyecto' data-col='Proyecto'/>
            <input autocomplete='off' class='filter' name='Trabajador' placeholder='Trabajador' data-col='Trabajador'/>
            <input autocomplete='off' class='filter' name='Año' placeholder='Año' data-col='Año'/>
            <input autocomplete='off' class='filter' name='Mes' placeholder='Mes' data-col='Mes'/>
        </div>
    </div>
    <table class="table" id="myTable">
        <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Proyecto</th>
            <th scope="col">Trabajador</th>
            <th scope="col">Año</th>
            <th scope="col">Mes</th>
            <th scope="col">Horas totales</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>1</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>2</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>3</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```